# Why is this C code involving constant pointer crashing on me?

Tags: c, code-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [getting segmentation fault in a small c program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250275/getting-segmentation-fault-in-a-small-c-program)

Here's my code:

```
char *const p1 = "john";

p1[2] = 'z';  //crashes

printf("%s\n", p1);
```

I know p1 is a "read-only" variable, but I thought I could still modify the string ("john" ). I appreciate any tips or advice.

Comment: http://c-faq.com/strangeprob/strlitnomod.html

Comment: @cnicutar - Precisely what I need Thank You So Much

Comment: Hmm, on this webpage - http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/10602/ - it says you could change John though

Comment: @Adel: it's wrong. Whether or not you can change "john" is implementation dependent. You can't rely on it, and therefore shouldn't to it.

Comment: `p1` does **not** have to be a read-only variable (you just added that restriction for no reason), but `*p1` **is** read-only. A small asterisk can make a big difference in C!

Comment: Modifying string literals is UB. Seg fault therefore perfectly  plausible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot safely modify string literals, even if the pointer doesn't look `const`. They will often be allocated in read-only memory, hence your crashes - and when they're not in read-only memory modifying them can have unexpected consequences.

If you copy to an array this should work:

```
char tmp[] = "john";
char *const p1 = tmp;
p1[2] = 'z'; // ok
```

Answer (score 3):

Keyword `const` means that variable of that type should stay constant. You shouldn't change it.

Also even if you declare this string as `char *p1 = "john";` it would be constant string literal and changing it would cause undefined behaviour. You should declare it as `char p1[] = "john";` in order to achieve behaviour you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

1) Forget the "const" qualifier.  This is *WRONG*, in C and C++, on *ANY* platform:

```
  char *p1 = "john";
  p1[2] = 'z';  //crashes
```

Here's why:

- [Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a string initialized with "char *s" but not "char s[]"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string)
- http://c-faq.com/decl/strlitinit.html

2) So how do you get around the access violation?

Simple: you allocate writable memory (instead of writing to a string constant, which is probably allocated in read-only memory):

```
  #define BUFSIZE 80
  ...
  char p1[BUFSIZE];
  strcpy (p1, "john");
  p1[2] = 'z';  //no problem
```

3) OK: so then what's the deal with "const"?

You were right about that part.  Here's (one of many) discussions about the (subtle) difference between a "const pointer" and a "pointer to a const":

http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/general/article.php/c6967

Answer (score 2):

your pointer points to memory that isn't allowed to be changed  ( the constant string )

do  `char p1[100] = "john";`

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are not supposed to modify constants: after all, they are called *constants* for a reason. Modifying a constant is undefined behavior according to the C standard, which often means that your program is going to crash.

Note that it has nothing to do with your *pointer* being constant: the crash is because what your pointer *points to* is a string constant.

Here is how to do what you are trying to do legally:

```
char p1[] = "john";
p1[2] = 'z';  //no longer crashes :)
printf("%s\n", p1);
```

Comment: That should not crash there - fix your comment :)

Comment: @bdonlan I modified the answer to point out that the crash is due to modifying a constant pointed to by the pointer, thanks for a good point.

Comment: What I mean is, you have a `//crashes` at a line that should not crash.

Comment: oh that's partly my fault! I should make it clearer like **CRASHEZ!**

Comment: @downvoter it is generally a good idea to explain your downvotes, especially for simple, correct answers. Once sentence is usually enough.

Answer (score 1):

There are two, unrelated, problems in that code. First, the `const` is not in the right place.

```
char * const p = "john";
char const * p = "john";
const char * p = "john";
```

The latter two are pointers to unmodifiable strings. If you had done this, then the code would not have compiled.

The first option `char * const` is not really a read-only variable. It means a pointer which points to modifiable data, and that the pointer cannot be changed such that it points to another string. But that's not relevant to your problem.

Your `const`is not relevant here. You have attempted to modify a string that shouldn't be modified. Literal strings should never be modified, and this is the cause of your crash.

Answer (score 0):

`p1` is a *pointer to constant data*, not a *constant pointer*.  Moreover it points to a *literal constant*, which typically resides in the code space, and modern operating systems and processors usually protect against code trying to modify code space.

You should not be surprised that it crashes, but in general the behaviour is undefined.